# How to get a local file via fetch/axios?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, axios, fetch-api

For study reasons I need to use some of these **network APIs** like **fetch** or **axios** but to get a **LOCAL** file, so **WITHOUT** using **fs** module, or **WITHOUT importing** them.

I tried with both fetch and axios, but they have not implemented this "feature" to get a local file, also because I think it's not so secure/safe.

fetch:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fetch('file://users.js')
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
        resolve(data);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error('Errore durante il recupero del file:', error);
        reject(error);
    });
});
```

I get this error:

> cause: Error: not implemented... yet...

axios:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        axios.get('file://users.js')
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response.data);
            resolve(response.data);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('Errore durante il recupero del file:', error);
            reject(error);
        });
    });
```

I get this error:

> generatedMessage: false,
> code: 'ERR_ASSERTION',
> actual: 'file:',
> expected: 'http:',
> operator: '=='

Is there some other network api that let me to that?

Comment: For security reasons, browsers cannot read local files in the same way they can read network resources. Consider using [`<input type="file">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file) instead.

Comment: Wouldn’t you be concerned if any website you browsed to could read files arbitrarily from your local disk?

Comment: _"For security reasons, browsers cannot read local files in the same way they can read network resources."_ Yes, they can.

Comment: If you're trying to use Fetch or Axios to access local files without using the file system module (fs), you might not find a straightforward solution because Axios library is primarily designed for making HTTP requests to remote servers. However, you can still achieve this by using JavaScript's fetch API with the file:// protocol.

Comment: @guest271314 not without end-user interaction

Comment: Yes, we can. Using multiple ways and means.

Comment: Please don't wrap `fetch()` in your own promise.  That's an anti-pattern.  Just use `return axios().then()` and it will return the naturally created promise.  Note even if your `fetch()` option would work, you also have to read the response with `res.text()` to get the actual data.  Axios reads its for you.

Comment: The simple answer is `node`s `fetch()` implementation does not  support `file:` protocol.

Comment: FYIL Relavant Node.js-specific issue https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/45798, Undici issue https://github.com/nodejs/undici/issues/2751, WinterCG issue https://github.com/wintercg/fetch/issues/5.

Comment: For the curious and motivated this is where undici's `fetch()` implemantion throws for `file:` protocol https://gist.github.com/guest271314/2779cfbb4a4f8ba3496e253e546c0104.

Comment: @ShenalMeghawarnadeSilva and what if I am not using fetch or axios? is there any other http-clients which allows also to get a local file?

Comment: @guest271314 do you know if is there any?

Answer (score -4):

To `fetch()` files on `file:` protocol in the browser you can create a browser extension, in `"host_permissions"` set `file:///*`, then you can fetch `file:` protocol using absolute path.

You can also `fetch()` `file:` protocol using `deno`.

Other options include WICG File System Access API `showOpenFilePicker()` or `showOpenDirectoryPicker()` where implemented, and `<input type="file">` which is implemented in all modern browsers.

Answer (score -4):

You can create an endpoint in your app to send the file by using res.sendFile function.

```
app.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
const File_Path = req.body.filepath;
res.sendFile(File_Path,{root: __dirname});
});
```

Now you can call this endpoint providing any path by axios and fetch and it will give you the file data.

Comment: That would send a local file from the _server_, not from the _client_.